# Python - Read Files based on Absolute Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am working with multiple audio files using Python 3.xx . I have listed all of files' absolute path in a txt file. There are 4 instrument type, Brass, String, Percussion, and Woodwind. The folder structure of the files look like this:

```
F:\Brass\Bass Trombone\BassTrombone.ff.stereo\BassTrombone.ff.A1.stereo.aif
.
.
F:\Percussion\Vibraphone\Vibraphone.shortsustain.ff.stereo\Vibraphone.shortsustain.ff.C4.stereo.aif
.
.
F:\String\Viola\Viola.arco.ff.sulC.stereo\Viola.arco.ff.sulC.F4.stereo.aif
.
.
F:\Woodwind\Bassoon\Bassoon.ff.stereo\Bassoon.ff.Eb3.stereo.aif
```

I want to process the files based on its absolute path, a bit like this:

```
if(filepath=='F:\Brass\*.aif'):
    #process Brass type audio file
elif(filepath=='F:\Percussion\*.aif'):
    #process Percussion type audio file
elif(filepath=='F:\String\*.aif'):
    #process String type audio file
elif(filepath=='F:\Woodwind\*.aif'):
    #process Woodwind type audio file
```

My question is how do I do this with Python 3.xx?. I am working on OS Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: As a side note: When using WIndows paths as literal strings, you should always use raw strings, like `r'F:\Brass\*.aif'` instead of plain strings, lik `'F:\Brass\*.aif'`. In your case, it just happens to be true that none of the backslash-sequences like `'\S'` are special escapes, and in Python (but not in many other languages) that means everything just works. But as soon as you add some more paths, you're going to hit one that is a special escape, and that's never fun to debug. If you start off with raw strings, the problem never comes up.

Answer (score 0):

For your described usecase, the easiest method would probably be the `startswith()` method:

```
if(filepath.startswith(r'F:\Brass)')
     #do something
```

Alternatively you could look for certain keywords in your path:

```
if('Brass' in filepath)
     #do something
```

Comment: Do I need to import certain module to do this?

Comment: Nope, they should work without importing any modules

Answer (score 0):

You *can* match a "glob pattern" like `'F:\Brass\*.aif'` using the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) module:

```
if fnmatch(filepath, r'F:\Brass\*.aif'):
```

---

However, it might be clearer to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to split up the path:

```
dname, fname = os.path.split(filepath)
name, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
if dname == r'F:\Brass' and ext == '.aif':
    # do stuff with filepath, or whichever part you split off
```

That also means you can replace the `if`/`elif` with, say, code that looks up a function or type in a dict:

```
kinds = {
    r'F:\Brass': handle_brass,
    r'F:\Percussion': handle_percussion,
    # etc.
}
dname, fname = os.path.split(filepath)
name, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
if dname in kinds and ext == '.aif':
    kinds[dname](filepath)
```

---

Although, looking at your examples, neither version is going to match something like `F:\Brass\Bass Trombone\BassTrombone.ff.stereo\BassTrombone.ff.A1.stereo.aif`. For glob patterns, `*.aif` only matches files in that directory, not in any subdirectory of that directory; you need a double-star recursive glob. And for `os.path.split`, you'll need to split all the way to the top-level parent, rather than just splitting once. But hopefully (with a bit of help from the docs) you can figure it out from here.