# (Python) file absolute path not work for file read/write

Tags: python, path, file-read

In linux system using python.I read through [Python - Read Files based on Absolute Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229666/python-read-files-based-on-absolute-pathbut) their solution is switch to 'F:', so is different from mine.

usb file path `/home/joy/aaa.txt` is what I can get, but file read/print only accept ,`/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt` path, (these 2 path point to same text file)

Question1:
I cannot generate `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt` path myself, so that I can't read/write

Question2:
or there is other way to read/write usb file

```
from pathlib import Path
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np
import os.path
from os import path

print("File      Path:", Path("aaa.txt").absolute())
print("Directory Path:", Path().absolute()) 


#with open('/home/joy/aaa.txt') as f:
#   contents_path1 = f.read()
#print(contents_path1)

with open('/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt') as f:
    contents_path2 = f.read()
print(contents_path2)
```

the output with `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt`  (can read/write , but I don't know how to get this path, another path just not work)-

```
File      Path: /home/joy/aaa.txt
Directory Path: /home/joy
The input:

5555555
66666666666
6
665
13
6
654521
```

tried code:  tried to use `os.path.abspath("relative path")` , but even is work, we just manual change `/home/joy/aaa.txt` to `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt`without the function can get relative path, in other USB plug in is not work again, so....

```
from pathlib import Path
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np
import os.path
from os import path


#with open('/home/joy/aaa.txt') as f:
#   contents_path1 = f.read()
#print(contents_path1)

with open('/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt') as f:
    contents_path2 = f.read()
print(contents_path2) 


dirname = os.path.dirname("aaa.txt")
filename = os.path.join(dirname, '/dadasad/aaa.txt')

print(filename) 

print("File      Path:", Path("aaa.txt").absolute())
print("Directory Path:", Path().absolute())
```

and the output is :

```
33333
55555

444

/dadasad/aaa.txt
File      Path: /home/joy/aaa.txt
Directory Path: /home/joy
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but I don't know how to get this path, another path just not work" I can't understand this. The code already has a working path in it, so how can you say "I don't know how to get this path"?

Comment: how can /home/joy/aaa.txt and /media/joy/aaa.txt be the same? it is like saying C:/path and D:/path is the same

Comment: hi @Karl Knechtel, for the txt file path `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt`in USB that I can do the read/write operation, is cool, but I have to click on every file's property to check path, that when I plug in other usb not as the same USB name "Data", is not work anymore. I'm working on something like `.absolute()` can get the relative path, to make it work, but instead of click every files properties, checking path, I don't know how to get `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt`, I'm not sure if I answer ur question

Comment: hi@Shravya Boggarapu, I think both path point to the same file, when I use `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt` path to read `aaa.txt` in usb, is working, even I change the contant, is also update when I read again (media path working). ;And use ` Path("aaa.txt").absolute()` output path `/home/joy/aaa.txt`, I'm pretty sure there is no other file in same name, so I could say both path point to same file, just I only know the function get `/home/joy/aaa.txt` but file read/write only work in path`/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the mode of opening the file like:

```
# for reading
with open('/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents_path2 = f.read()
print(contents_path2) 

with open('/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: thanks @awied1404, but input absolute path `with open('/home/joy/aaa.txt', 'r') as f:` to ur function also not working(path issue), the situation is the same that only work in path `/media/joy/Data/aaa.txt'`. However, I don't know how to use python get /media/joy/Data/aaa.txt'` path, for `Path("aaa.txt").absolute()` absolute path is not working in this condition.

Comment: it looks like your home directory is actually not at /. Do a pwd in the current directory and check?

Comment: you can always use os.path.abspath("relative path")

Comment: I just update the tried code on  post @Shravya Boggarapu, but I think it may not solved  question

Comment: To get the absolute path u can use os.path.abspath() but you still need to know the relative path